# Strange Exception from HRESULT: 0x80030102 (STG_E_REVERTED) error

Tags: sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-workflow

I have a strange one here.

I've added a 2010 sharepoint workflow to sharepoint, without any problems. The workflow works without any problems.

However, when I try to add the workflow column to the default view (so I can see the status of any running workflows, while I'm browsing the document library) I get the following error:

> Attempted to use an object that has ceased to exist. (Exception from
>   HRESULT: 0x80030102 (STG_E_REVERTED))

If I remove the column from the view, the view works correctly. Add the column back, and I get that error.

Any suggestions on how to fix this one?

Thanks!

Comment: ok, I don't know how to close out my question, but I found the answer. Basically, after adding 24 columns to a view, this exception is thrown. Once I removed a lesser valuable column, the error went away.